# How to prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx$ converges without calculating the limit

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I am given $\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx$ and asked to prove that it converges and if it does, calculate the integral.

I have calculated the integral and it gives 1. However, I cannot find a way to prove that it converges before calculating the limit.

Comment: Indeed, you are done.  One way to prove an improper integral converges is to evaluate it.

Comment: The question was worded in a was that made it obvious I need to prove that it converges first.

Comment: If this is a question from a course you're taking, get verification from your instructor that yours is the correct interpretation.  I would never ask a question that way and expect separate arguments for (a) convergence and (b) the value it converges to.  When I write the question this way, I want the students to either (1) show that the integral converges by evaluating it, or (2) show that the integral diverges by verifying $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b f(x)\,dx$ does not exist.

Comment: My teacher assigned this right after teaching the comparison theory. I'm sure this time he wants us to use it rather than proving with limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $e^{x}\ge x^3$ for $x>M$ when $M$ large enough, and we know $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x} dx=\int_0^M xe^{-x} dx+\int_M^\infty xe^{-x} dx$.

$\int_M^\infty xe^{-x} dx\le \int_M^\infty x \dfrac{1}{x^3} dx<\infty$.

Also $\int_0^M xe^{-x} dx<\infty$ since the integrand is continuous.

Comment: I'm not sure the comparison to $x^3$ is obvious, but the comparison to $x^3/6$ is, and that would do the job here.

Comment: @lan Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have modified my solution to express my original idea.

Answer (score 1):

Enforce the substitution $x\to \log(x)$ and write

$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}\,dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2}\,dx$$

Then, note that for any $\alpha>0$ and $x\ge 1$, we have

$$0\le \log(x)\le \frac{x^{\alpha}-1}{\alpha} \tag 1$$

Can you finish?

---

**NOTE:**

To establish the inequalities in $(1)$, we use the result from [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) in which I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{z-1}{z}\le \log(z)\le z-1 \tag 2$$

for $z>0$.  Now, since

$$\log(x^\alpha)=\alpha \log(x)$$

we establish the right-hand side inequality of $(1)$ by letting $z=x^\alpha$ in $(2)$ using $(3)$, and dividing by $\alpha>0$.

The left-hand side inequality of $(1)$ is true since $\log(x)$ is monotonically increasing with $\log(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another comparison method.  We can use L'Hôpital's Rule to show that
$$
    \lim_{x\to\infty} xe^{-x/2} = 0
$$
Therefore there exists a number $M$ such that 
$$
0 < x e^{-x/2} < 1 \quad\text{when $x>M$}
$$
It follows that
$$
x e^{-x} < e^{-x/2} \quad\text{when $x>M$}
$$
So you can use the Comparison test to show that $\int_M^\infty xe^{-x}\,dx$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

A standard inequality yields, for $x\ge 0$:
$$0\le \frac{x}{2}\le e^\frac{x}{2}\,. $$
Hence 
$$ \int_0^{X} x e^{-x}$$
being the integral of a non-negative function is increasing, and bounded above by 
$$ \int_0^{X} 2  e^{\frac{x}{2}} e^{-x} $$
which converges. Hence the integral is convergent.